# How to submit an App to AppStore from other Mac?

Tags: ios, app-store

I've written an app on Mac Mini 1 and submitted to the appstore using the installed code signings and provisioning profiles.

I now have a new Mac Mini 2 with better speed and memory. So I moved my app to it.

How do I submit the same app with the new Mac Mini 2? Because my provisioning profile and code signing key is installed on Mac Mini 1. How can I do it?

Comment: Search Keychain Access - > select your distribution profile for app store -> right click this profile and Click to export. and install it to another mac.

Comment: http://www.ironpaper.com/webintel/articles/how-to-share-an-ios-distribution-certificate/#.Vm6epDZpVTZ

Answer (score 8):

you should export both your certificate and private key from you old Mac, and import it to your new mac. Then you can simply download and install profile from developer.apple.com.

[image]

Or if you can't do this, you can simply revoke and remake your certificate and profile from apple account. It will not break your already distributed applications. The only thing, you must keep your application identifier the same.